# Deserializing bad data structure with JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, customization, json.net

Due to circumstances beyond my control (the SurveyGizmo API), I have to deserialize data held in the following (sample) format:

```
// Data in JSON format as produced by API
[{
    "id": "2",
    "contact_id": "",
    "status": "Deleted",
    "is_test_data": "1",
    "datesubmitted": "2012-11-12 08:41:49",
    "sResponseComment": "",
    "[question(3)]": "fsdfsd",
    "[question(4), option(10001)]": "",
    "[question(4), option(10002)]": "Some answer",
    "[question(5), option(10008)]": "",
    "[question(5), option(10009)]": "Other administrative role"
},{
    etc.
}]
```

I'm using [JSON.Net](http://bit.ly/VxCWDx) to decode it, and ideally want to pull those question entries out into a keyed structure: question[qnum][optnum].

I am fine working with multidimensional arrays, and am fine using RegEx to split the questions and options apart as needed, but I can't find working examples sufficient to get me started on writing a custom JSONConverter to contain the code.

So far, I've found the following (ISurveyObject constrains types that I will be deserializing, and specifies certain common properties)

```
class SurveyGizmoJsonArrayConverter<T> : Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.CustomCreationConverter<T[]> where T : ISurveyObject
{
    public override T[] Create(Type objectType)
    {
        List<T> retArr = new List<T>();
        return retArr.ToArray();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // What goes here? I can't seem to find working examples...
    }
}
```

Can anyone offer any help or code samples please?

I suppose that maybe the most useful code snippet would be what I would need to put in the ReadJson function to make it do plain vanilla deserializing - I can then tweak that for the special cases...

Comment: You might find this post helpful:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252176/json-net-deserializeobject-format

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
var listofDicts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, object>>>(json);
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question: the point is that the JSON structure is bad, so using your code, I get a `List` of `Dictionary<string,object>` where the keys are strings like `[question(4), option(10053)], ` and `[question(4), option(10054)], `.
The point of a custom deserializer would be to get a `List` of `Dictionary<string,object>` where some of the objects are themselves multidimensional structures. Something like:
`dict { [somekey] => 'somevalue', [question] => { [4] => { [10053] => 'ans1', [10054] => 'ans2' } } }`
(sorry, code formatting doesn't work in comments)